# Is considring new keyword the elements inside the class that are initialized by the default constructor also with new keyword in C++?

Tags: c++, new-operator, default-constructor

Initializing a class that has members dynamically allocated.
Does new keyword to allocate the entire block of memory taking into account the members that will be also initialized inside the class by the default constructor?

Should I care about where these members are placed in memory (sparsed or put together)? I'm working with huge arrays of vertex in a recursive algorithm that performs adaptive mesh refinement based on some error criteria. And I need to traverse those arrays to do other operations so I need performance.

Also, as a related topic. Is one of the two ways used below to declare a class inside main function preferred in terms of performance?

Could you recommend me some book/article/webpage about this topics?

Example of a toy-code that summarizes the issue:

```
class Octree {

    vec3* Vertex;
    vec3* Cell_Centers;

    public:

    Octree(unsigned population_to_allocate) //constructor
    {
        Vertex = new vec3[population_to_allocate*8];
        Cell_Centers = new vec3[population_to_allocate];
    }

int main()
{
    unsigned population_to_allocate = 3000;
    Octree* newOctree = new Octree(population_to_allocate);
    Octree stackOctree(population_to_allocate);
}
```

Comment: Your example won't compile, as `Octree` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: How large is `population_to_allocate` typically, and how many `Octree`s do you construct?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I will construct up to seven Octree's and `population_to_allocate` is around of thousands of elements. Sorry @IgorTandetnik I've tried to focus just on the code of interest. Here is my repository where I'm actually working [link](https://github.com/rockSaMy/setMeshEngine/blob/refresh_v0.18/src/geometry/structuredHexMesh.h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you've said the number of `Octree`s is at most seven and `population_to_allocate` is in the thousands, the simplest efficient thing you can do is to change from `vec3*` to `std::vector<vec3>`.  Then your constructor will look like this:

```
Octree(unsigned population_to_allocate) //constructor
    : Vertex(population_to_allocate)
    , Cell_Centers(population_to_allocate)
{
}
```

By not using `new`, you'll avoid memory leaks and errors easily.  And there's no reason to complicate things more than this, because you only have a handful of `Octree` instances.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion. It is the key to improve the performance a lot. Since using `std::vector<vec3>` for those arrays I can **add** or **remove** the elements of the mesh that changes between iterations instead of create and delete the entire class each time. So even if some Octree Depth Levels aren't neccesary in some time steps there is no reason to remove the entire class to re-allocate in memory againg before, instead to simply adapt the size of `std::vector<vec3>`. I will update the rate of improve after I'll implement it. Thanks!